# Invisible line breaks in txt file: "\n", "r", or something else?

Tags: html, notepad++

There are some online txt files. When I view them in Chrome, the text is broken into lines properly. When I copied them to MS-Word, there are also line breaks. However, when I downloaded them and opened them in Notepad, there are no line breaks. Are these line breaks "\n" or "\r" or something else?

Here is an example as shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried opening them in notepad++?  This sounds like the file has unix-style line endings, which don't get properly displayed in regular notepad.
DOS uses carriage return and line feed ("\r\n") as a line ending, while Unix uses just line feed ("\n")

Comment: notepad++ display the line breaks properly.

Comment: What does it say the end of line characters are?  I'd be willing to bet "LF" (aka "\n")

Comment: How to see it? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's "LF".